# Scroll to index in GridView

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, winrt-xaml

I have a GridView with *n* number of items. Only 50 are loaded in at a time. Is there a way to jump the GridView control to a specific index without just scrolling through the GridView until that item is available? I dont want to do it that way for obvious visual and memory reasons.

Thanks,
Dom

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into `ISupportIncrementalLoading` to support data virtualization. That way your `ItemsSource` might say it has 1000 items, but not load them all and your `GridView` will be able to skip to say 600-700 range and your `ItemsSource` will only load the items from that specific range. You can then use the `ScrollIntoView()` method to do the actual scrolling to the specified item.

Comment: Thats exactly what it is doing, but now how do I jump to another part of the datasource (say, half way) without loading all the stuff that I dont need along the way, but still allowing the user to scroll back if they want.

Comment: Using the [`ScrolIntoView()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.scrollintoview.aspx) method on the `GridView`. That shouldn't load anything on the way there.